# How to keep track of all the processes on your server and have it send emails whenever an unwanted process begins?

Tags: shell, scripting

I have been trying to get more into scripting and programming and I am doing most of this on my Mac. I have been trying to monitor all the processes on my server and have a somewhat basic understanding of scripting with bash. 
For the mailing part of the question, I know a variety of people have asked this question and there have been a variety of answers, but none of the answers seem to work for me. I have tried:

```
 5 #!/bin/bash
  6 sed <<"ENDMAIL" -e '/^From [^ ]/s/^From /From  /' -e 's/^\.$/. /' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -f "$sender"
  7 To: $receiver1, $receiver2, $receiver3
  8 From: $sender
  9 Subject: $subj
 10 Any-Other-Standard-Optional-Headers: place headers in any order, including,
 11 MIME-Version: 1.0
 12 Content-Type: text/plain;
 13 X-Mailer: any identity you want to give your E-mailing application
 14 X-Your-Custom-Headers: X- headers can be your own private headers
 15 x-Last-Header: a blank line MUST follow the last header
 16 
 17 Your body text here
 18 
 19 ENDMAIL-s "$subj"
```

I also tried using mail:

```
 23 cat myfile.txt | mail -s " Hi My mail goes here " anemail@gmail.com
```

For the second part of the question, I understand the basics on how to view all the processes taking place, but I don't know how to compare all the processes at the current time to those at any other time. I have used the ps commands (like ps aux) to view all the processes, but how would I save those and then compare it at a later time.
Thanks for your time and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why you don't using zabbix or even collectd as a monitoring plan for your server(s)?

Comment: Put your unwanted process names in a file (one-per-line), then `ps -xaf | grep -f unwantedfile; if [ $? -eq '0' ] | mail yourself`. You can create a number of variations on this theme, like writing the results of `grep` to a tmp file and attaching that to your email, etc..

Comment: @HamidYousefi I am mostly doing this to try to get a better understanding of scripting so I can apply it to other things later on.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that method looks good, but what if I don't know the actual process thats running when it shouldn't be?